# Сортировка матрицы строками

Tags: c++, матрицы

Нужно отсортировать матрицу по строкам. Матрица n*2 цифр. Известно, что значение элемента слева, больше или равно элементу справа. Нужно отсортировать матрицу по возрастанию (считать от левого столбца)

Например, пусть матрица 4*2:
5 4 
3 2 
6 3 
2 1

Результат: 
2 1 
3 2 
5 4 
6 3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, wi, hi, flag, id; cin >> n;
    int pad[100][100];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            cin >> pad[i][j];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            cout << pad[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){ //сортировка по длине\ширине
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            if (pad[i][0] < pad[i][1]){
                flag = pad[i][0];
                pad[i][0] = pad[i][1];
                pad[i][1] = flag;
            }
        }
    }

    /*вот тут нужна сортировка строками*/

    cout << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            cout << pad[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: вам задано фиксированное количество столбцов _ всего два столбца. Зачем нужен массив 100 * 100?